# Merge and stacking data in R

Tags: r, merge, reshape

For example, there is time series data with a different number of columns and will be combined by adding new columns. I'm having trouble merging and stacking them because the column names are unrecognizable.

```
#First data
name1<-c("Andi","Ani","Juli")
dd<-matrix(rnorm(36),ncol=3);dd<-as.data.frame(dd)
colnames(dd)<-name1;dd1<-dd;nd1<-nrow(dd1)
n1<-ncol(dd1)
#Second data
name2<-c("Andi","Ani","Juli","Juni")
dd<-matrix(rnorm(80),ncol=4);dd<-as.data.frame(dd)
colnames(dd)<-name2;dd2<-dd
n2<-ncol(dd2);nd2<-nrow(dd2)
#Merge & Stacking
DaRR<-NULL
for(i in 1:n2){
nna2<-name2[i]
DaRR_<-NULL
for(j in 1:n1){
    nna1<-name2[j]
    if(nna2 == nna1){
        DaRR_<-c(dd1[,i],dd2[,j])
    }else{
        next
    }
dupl<-rep("XXX",nd1)
DaRR_<-c(dupl,dd2[,i])
}
DaRR<-cbind(DaRR,DaRR_)
}
```

Desired result:

```
      DaRR_                 DaRR_                DaRR_                DaRR_
[1.]  -1.9470804 -0.15451553  1.69498001  "XXX"
[2.]  -0.2311135  1.14891305  0.17395141  "XXX"
[3,]   0.9371293  1.48934820  0.33862342  "XXX"
[4,]  -0.3381575  1.76123310  0.93475370  "XXX"
[5,]   2.1347953  0.46455408 -0.03283264  "XXX"
[6,]  -1.2142898 -1.00940986  0.12973995  "XXX"
[7,]  -0.7788720  0.46866536  0.18310776  "XXX"
[8,]  -0.8667355 -1.85909721 -1.05711808  "XXX"
[9,]   0.9289370 -0.25421140 -0.13492044  "XXX"
[10,] -0.3007262  0.30409309  0.54958016  "XXX"
[11,] -0.3805569 -0.09353285  2.27405059  "XXX"
[12,]  0.7587997  0.80732128  0.03422467  "XXX"
[13,] "1.34696898710666"    "-0.198851239901805" "0.334057783172022"  
[14,] "-0.435942723430498"  "0.306828387912936"  "-0.938523307710521" 
[15,] "-0.265285902944808"  "0.721459014968174"  "-1.82707007543666"  
[16,] "1.58759166754201"    "-1.47614456502887"  "-1.21306832466975"  
[17,] "0.424393481053464"   "0.655826393660495"  "0.288243529871784"  
[18,] "-0.65438898526425"   "-0.640742323728014" "0.693551868680085"  
[19,] "-1.80833220993313"   "-0.897518866526767" "-1.73897841823514"  
[20,] "-0.0660275125014107" "0.140663303366014"  "-1.21130608877615"  
[21,] "1.85286698109007"    "-1.30771714034588"  "-0.928005801280665" 
[22,] "1.30168226335214"    "0.881285603015683"  "-1.24954972323302"  
[23,] "0.478732452440329"   "1.58022368211514"   "-0.0864943280820771"
[24,] "-1.81765850980761"   "0.66571286028555"   "-2.55600015433571"  
[25,] "-0.667110842664888"  "0.952606783138395"  "-0.0239496256536243"
[26,] "1.251596581557"      "-0.673926090970423" "-0.922582582633877" 
[27,] "-1.7415929470951"    "-1.60271402324792"  "0.0486990326594654" 
[28,] "-0.286027857835192"  "0.183397655741827"  "0.334799213547238"  
[29,] "-0.152689370749341"  "1.18276041450592"   "0.952138672622552"  
[30,] "1.34231553537835"    "-1.01358652507626"  "0.461571536335735"  
[31,] "-0.02608063103647"   "0.487607550927421"  "0.334013197562071"  
[32,] "0.792308074641114"   "-1.3595426981532"   "-1.61478080821833"
```

How to make the data combination as desired?

Comment: I've been trying to figure out what you are trying to achieve. I'm not the greatest at data wrangling but I think this question needs more clarity. First, you won't be able to have character strings and numeric values in the output. Second, in the desired output the first value in the first `DaRR_` column is not found anywhere in the input data `DaRR`. Are you expecting to perform some calculation on the data to arrive at the expected output?

Comment: @dandrews - TL;DR ignore the values in that matrix, they are randomly generated. `rnorm()` generates a normally distributed vector of random numbers. Unless you run the same `set.seed()` you'll get different values. The OP didn't do a `set.seed()` so we can't replicate the values in that matrix. Note that you have to run `set.seed()` then `rnorm()` each time if you want the same output values.

Comment: I am assuming that 1) you want to keep your numeric values as numeric 2) the example you provide is not complete (given your loop) 3) you want to know which data refers to the values in "names2". With that in mind, from the `dplyr` package you could use `DaRR <- bind_rows(dd1, dd2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this:

```
dd3 <- dplyr::bind_rows(dd1, dd2)
```

or even:

```
dd3 <- plyr::rbind.fill(dd1, dd2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to construct `for` loops because R has some great functions for this kind of thing.

You can do this in base R as follows:

```
dd3 = merge(dd1, dd2, all=T)
```

or use the dplyr pacakge:

```
dd3 = dplyr::full_join(dd1, dd2)
```

You can then rename the columns in base R

```
names(dd3) <- c("DaRR1", "DaRR2" , "DaRR3" , "DaRR4"  )
```

or using the `dplyr::rename()` function.

On the other hand, I don't suggest replacing the NAs with "XXX" since this will require your column to be treated as a character vector instead of a numeric vector (you can't do calculations with a character vector).